# Theorem regarding independent sets in a graph G= (V,E)

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering about the following equivalent statements concerning a graph $G(V,E)$ and a subset $S \subseteq V$:

1. S is an independent set
2. $V-S$ is a vertex cover
3. S is a clique in the complemented graph $\bar{G}= (V,\bar{E})$, where two vertices are adjacent iff they are not adjacent in $G$.

If I for example consider the following graph where I've tried to illustrate the statements:

[image: 1) I.P set , 2) vertex cover, 3) a clique]

For the second statement I end up with a null graph with no edges, so is the vertex cover just the empty set in this case?

This seems intuitive enough when considering an example. I would be curious about how I would prove these equivalences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V\setminus S$ is a set of vertices. It does not affect the edge set.

The proofs are more or less direct after you write down the definitions.  For example, for 1 implies 3, let $i$ and $j$ be arbitrary vertices in $S$. By definition of independent set, $(i,j)\notin E$. By definition of complement, $(i,j)\in \bar{E}$. Because $i$ and $j$ were arbitrary, we have shown that $S$ is a clique in $\bar{G}$.